# What are possible fields' filters in Joomla module parameters?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

I am looking for possible filters' list when adding parameters' field for a module settings.

I know that filter="raw" and filter="integer" exists from examples at [Text form field type](http://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type).

But what are other possible filters for these fields?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not totally sure if this is it, but may want to see this list [directly from the code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php#L167), with the method `clean()`.

So the list would be:

- INT / INTEGER
- UINT
- FLOAT / DOUBLE
- BOOL / BOOLEAN
- WORD
- ALNUM
- CMD
- BASE64
- STRING
- HTML
- ARRAY
- PATH
- USERNAME
- RAW

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: EMAIL doesn't do anything in this case. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: There should also be `media` for images... at least I'm using it. Personally I'm looking for something like URL...

Comment: "safehtml" was added I think

Answer (score 2):

Posting as a guest so I couldn't comment ;) You might also find the list of available field types useful for capturing data like URLs and emails. You can find the full list [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types). Also available in the folder structure at `libraries/cms/form/field` and `libraries/joomla/form/fields`. There are URL and email fields which, I believe, include the relevant filtering. Usage would be as follows in the .xml:

```
<field name="myAwesomeURL" type="url" class="awesome"></field>
```

This renders as a text input box.

Comment: I think he was asking about `filter`, not `field`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's worthwhile to know URL and EMAIL field types already exist.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, Joomla starts applying the filter with [this `filterField`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/67423bb0894cc6747e12e626770e7c53cb715565/libraries/joomla/form/form.php#L1234) function. In this code, you can see some more `filter` types like `TEL`, `SAFEHTML` or so. From this function, if there's no match, it will go further to the one mentioned by @ValentinDespa. It also enables you to call your own function, as long as it's "callable". I found out this scattering after I looked into code by another dev having `filter="intval"`.

Hope that helps!